# PatchCollection does not preserve hatches with match_original=True

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7

I am writing a code that needs to spam a `PatchCollection` on a plot.

Some `Patch`s in the `PatchCollection` are shaded with `hatch="/"` argument.

But these hatches does not seem to be preserved in `PatchCollection` even if I used `match_original=True` when creating the `PatchCollection` object.

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = Wedge((0,0),1,0,360, facecolor="cyan", hatch="/")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_patch(w)
plt.show()
```

Of course, I had more than a patch in my actual application.

Above script gave me a plot like this:

[image]

But when I tried to do the same thing with `PatchCollection`:

```py
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = Wedge((0,0),1,0,360, facecolor="cyan", hatch="/")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection([w],match_original=True))
plt.show()
```

[image]

The hatches are gone.

Comment: As noted in the [PatchCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection) docs, `match_original` only applies to colors and linewidths.

Comment: @BigBen Oh... I thought hatches will be preserved as they are governed by the edgecolor. Is there a handy workaround?

Comment: I don't know of one. Any other kwargs are passed through to [`Collection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection), which has its own `hatch` parameter. So I don't see how `PatchCollection` will be helpful for your case.